# CSS Overrides to a joomla Module Class not working for IE 11 & Chrome(working for ff)

Tags: css, joomla

I did used module class suffix to change the header text to a header picture for  the modules on my Joomla site on my local host. the changes show good in FF but not in IE11 or Chrome 43.0.I checked in task inspector in all 3 browsers and find that the CSS overrides file is not kicking in in IE and Chrome.

Comment: How are you adding it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a browser cache issue? Have you tried clearing your cache?